# C# HttpWebReqest - escape POST content?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, escaping

When I've uploaded content from my C# app to a website in the past, I've used a POST request like so:

```
    HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + this.server + "/log.php");
    wr.Method = "POST";
    wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string paramString = "v=" + this.version + "&m=" + this.message;
    wr.ContentLength = paramString.Length;
    StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(wr.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    stOut.Write(paramString);
    stOut.Close();
```

My problem is that now I'm in a situation where `this.message` will very likely contain newlines, tabs, and special characters including "&" and "=".  Do I need to escape this content.  If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode/HtmlDecode or UrlEncode/UrlDecode as appropriate.

Comment: Yup.  UrlEncode was what I needed:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx
Thanks.

Comment: (If you're not finding it with Intellisense, make sure you're referencing the System.Web assembly.)

Comment: yeah... just saw that.  Sorry. I saw the .Net 3.5 on the doc page and got scared.  Jumped the gun a little.

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, the solution to my problem was in:

[`System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)

Which is supported by all versions of the .Net framework =p

Specifically, I'm using the overload that takes a [string as an argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx).  Running this on all parameter values will make them safe for POSTing.

Answer (score 1):

System.Web is outdated - use `System.Net.WebUtility` instead...